# Reload a url in each seconds with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want reload a url in each seconds with jquery, i try as following code, this code reloading url only once. How do i do?

```
<a href="http://myweb.com/" id="thisLink"></a>

setInterval(window.location = $('#thisLink').attr('href'), 1000);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QBMLm/

Comment: This is really annoying, but there actually is a meta refresh tag that does this without any javascript at all.

Answer (score 1):

If it's your page, you can use this in the head :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=/">
```

of course, this only works for the page it's embedded in, and won't keep reloading some other external site?

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is not persistent between browser reloads. Also, it takes a function as first argument. You can try something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = $('#thisLink').attr('href');
}, 1000);
```

It will wait 1sec before redirecting. If the page you are redirecting to have the same code, it will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Once you re-load the url (`window.location` change) the context (and scope) of that `setInterval` become moot (the page is discarded and the next is loaded). The script's then reloaded and `setInterval` reassigned.

Oh, and syntactically that code is invalid. You probably want to wrap the `window.location` portion in a `function(){}`, e.g.

```
setInterval(function(){
  window.location = $('#thisLink').attr('href')
}, 1000);
```

otherwise it's not actually executing in an interval fashion, but immediately.

Comment: @jenniferJolie: That's what i explained in the first half of my aswer. You can't use `setInterval` and `window.location` in the same statement (but did show how it _should_ look while retaining the code).

Answer (score 0):

It's reloading only once, since once you change `window.location` you leave your page.

You need to open the link in new named window or embed the *child page* in an iframe.

```
setInterval(function() {
    window.open($('#thisLink').attr('href'), 'mywindow', '');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Look that these which may help you:

[JS setInterval executes only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746505/js-setinterval-executes-only-once)
[setInterval with jQuery.html only updates once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412591/setinterval-with-jquery-html-only-updates-once)
http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+setinterval+only+running+once&aq=0&oq=jquery+setinterval+only+running+once&sugexp=chrome,mod=1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8